# How to debug asp in VS 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, asp-classic

as the title says my question would be how to debug old asp code in VS2008 SP1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/DebugVBScriptVS2008.aspx) on CodeProject explaining it step by step and also [this post](http://codepagoda.com/2009/04/30/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio-2008-sp1-and-35-framework/).